# Adding new property in response JSON

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to add any new value to the array which is storing a response in JSON.

pict is an array in JS
this.pict.push(new Error(JSON.stringify(responseholder)

let me know if i can add new string A and String B in responseholder as field.

Comment: just want to add method name and component name in the JSON object

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add properties to your JSON.

```
responseholder.methodName = 'methodName';
responseholder.componentName = 'componentName';
```

So it will look like:

```
JSON.stringify(responseholder);
{"country":"FR","name":"Lyon","lat":"45.75","lng":"4.583333","methodName":"methodName","componentName":"componentName"}"
```